# Se deben cerrar los FileInputStream y FileOutputStream usados por clase Properties?

Tags: java

He visto que para leer o escribir ficheros se debe cerrar (**close()**) los objetos **FileInputStream** y **FileOutputStream** usados, ya que si esas transmisiones quedan abiertas consumen recursos.

Quisiera saber si en este caso también aplica, o no es lo correcto:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Propiedades {
    private static Properties config;
    private static FileOutputStream out;
    private static FileInputStream in;

    public Propiedades() {
        config = new Properties();
    }


    public String loadConfig(String nomProp) { 
        try 
        { 
            //esto funciona solo ejecutando desde jar
            File jarFile = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
            in =new FileInputStream(jarFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()+"/config.properties");
            config.load(in);

            //este es para desarrollo, ejecutando desde compilador
//            config.load(this.getClass().
//                getResourceAsStream("/propiedades/config.properties")); 

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error cargando configuración\n" + e.getMessage()
                    , "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                in.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Propiedades.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return config.getProperty(nomProp);
    }

    public void setPropertyValue(String property, String value) {
        //solo funciona ejecutando desde jar
        config.setProperty(property, value);
        try 
        { 
            File jarFile = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
            out = new FileOutputStream(jarFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()+"/config.properties");
            config.store(out, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            Logger.getLogger(Propiedades.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            try 
            {
                out.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Propiedades.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, también aplica, te recomiendo particularmente hacer uso del try con recursos que se encarga por tí de cerrar los recursos que haya usado al final del bloque; esta característica existe dede java 7.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Propiedades {
    private static Properties config;


    public Propiedades() {
        config = new Properties();
    }


    public String loadConfig(String nomProp) {


        try {
            File jarFile = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());

            try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(jarFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/config.properties")) {
                //esto funciona solo ejecutando desde jar

                config.load(in);

                //este es para desarrollo, ejecutando desde compilador
                //            config.load(this.getClass().
                //                getResourceAsStream("/propiedades/config.properties"));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error cargando configuración\n" + e.getMessage()
                        , "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (
                URISyntaxException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error cargando configuración\n" + e.getMessage()
                    , "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        return config.getProperty(nomProp);
    }

    public void setPropertyValue(String property, String value) {
        //solo funciona ejecutando desde jar
        config.setProperty(property, value);

        try {
            File jarFile = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());

            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(jarFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/config.properties")) {
                config.store(out, null);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Propiedades.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(Propiedades.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adopté tu recomendación, gracias!